# Dynamic generation of Buttons

Tags: dynamic, symbols, button

### The Project

I am trying to dynamically turn on/off the display of data for a [circos](http://circos.ca/)-esque plot that I generated.

[image: Data Plot]

### The Code

I have data stored in `mfData` and a compiled list of data about that in `mfIndex`, primarily used for how many data sets there are (number of sectors, etc.).

Here are the steps that I have taken (3 & 4 are wrapped in `Dynamic[]`):

1. **Variables** - I started the dynamic compilation of the code under the impression that I would need a variable for each sector set to True/False.  So I generated n expressions and evaluated each to True to start off.

   `vars = Table[ToExpression[StringJoin["sector", ToString[n], "=True"]], {n, 1, Length[mfIndex]}]`
2. **Outer Rings** - The rings are generated and wrapped in `Button[]` which switches the variable

   `oRings = Table[Button[{color, Tooltip[Rotate[ring[outer_radius, inner_radius, angular_size], angle, {0, 0}], "Text"]}, (Symbol[StringJoin["sector", ToString[m]]] = Symbol[StringJoin["sector", ToString[m]]] /. {True -> False, False -> True})], {m, 1, Length[mfIndex]}]`
3. **Choice** - My hope was that the button directive would turn each variable to True/False when being clicked which would update pick and curves

   `pick = Pick[Range[Length[mfIndex]],vars]`
4. **Curves** - The Bezier Curves are generated

   `curves = Table[Table[BezierCurve[{pt1, pt2, pt3}],{n,1,Length[mfData[[n]]]}],{n,pick}]`

### The (Apparent) Problem

There are no errors when evaluated, but when I click on one of the rings an error comes up (I tried using both `ToExpression[]` and `Symbol[]` in the Outer Ring evaluation)

```
Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[sectorm] is Protected. >>
Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[sectorm] is Protected. >>
```

Meaning that when the Outer Ring code is evaluated the variables aren't being processed into their proper form... "sectorm" instead of {sector1, sector2, etc...}.

I know this is a bit long-winded to get to this question, but is there a better way to evaluate (compose) the variables?  **Or** to accomplish the same thing or re-evaluating the display of data?

(I can provide more explanation if necessary, I tried to reduce this a bit for simplicity's sake...)

---

### (Update) Minimal non-working example

(I think that copied over correctly...)

```
ring[o_, i_, s_, p_] := Module[{q, oP, iP, cut}, q = (s)/(2 Pi); oP = Table[{o Cos[k q 2 Pi/p], o Sin[k q 2 Pi/p]}, {k, 1, p}]; iP = Table[{i Cos[k q 2 Pi/p], i Sin[k q 2 Pi/p]}, {k, 1, p}]; cut = Polygon[Flatten[{oP, Reverse@iP}, 1]]; Return[cut]];

cir[x_, r_] := {r*Cos[x], r*Sin[x]}

Dynamic[vars = Table[ToExpression[StringJoin["sector", ToString[n]]], {n, 1, 8}]];

Table[ToExpression[StringJoin["sector", ToString[n], "=True"]], {n, 1, 8}];

points1 = Table[{RandomReal[{0 + m*(Pi/4), Pi/4 + m*(Pi/4) - Pi/64}], RandomReal[{0 + (m + 2)*(Pi/4), Pi/4 + (m + 2)*(Pi/4)}]}, {4}, {m, 0, 7}];

points2 = Table[Table[{points1[[n, o, 1]], If[Abs[points1[[n, o, 2]] - points1[[n, o, 1]]] > Pi, (points1[[n, o, 1]] + points1[[n, o, 2]])/2 + Pi, (points1[[n, o, 1]] + points1[[n, o, 2]])/2], points1[[n, o, 2]]}, {o, 1, 8}], {n, 1, 4}];

Dynamic[outRing = Table[Button[Rotate[ring[1.1, 1.05, Pi/4 - Pi/64, 1000], Pi/4*(n - 1), {0, 0}], (ToExpression[StringJoin["sector", ToString[n], "=", ToString[Not[Symbol[StringJoin["sector", ToString[n]]]]]]])], {n, 1, 8}]];

Dynamic[pick = Pick[Range[8], Table[Symbol[StringJoin["sector", ToString[n]]], {n, 1, 8}]]];

Dynamic[inCurve = Table[Table[BezierCurve[{cir[points2[[o, n, 1]], 1], cir[points2[[o, n, 2]], 0.3], cir[points2[[o, n, 3]], 1]}], {n, pick}], {o, 1, 4}]];

Dynamic[Graphics[{outRing, inCurve}]]
```

[image: Simple working example]

Comment: Change the swapper to something like `ToExpression[
 StringJoin["sector", ToString[m], "=", 
  ToString[Not[Symbol[StringJoin["sector", ToString[m]]]]]]]`

Comment: Nope... I get this: $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

Comment: Which I guess actually does get rid of the problem of the variable expression not evaluating...

Comment: Works fine for me in my test framework. Perhaps update your post to provide a minimal non-working example.

Comment: I'll assume in your actual code (vs simplified) you're properly controlling the evaluation in the button creation, e.g. with something like `Table[
 With[{z = m},
  Button[{color, 
    Tooltip[Rotate[ring[outer_radius, inner_radius, angular_size], 
      angle, {0, 0}], "Text"]}, (ToExpression[
     StringJoin["sector", ToString[z], "=", 
      ToString[
       Not[Symbol[StringJoin["sector", ToString[z]]]]]]])]], {m, 1, 
  3}]`

Comment: Is there a benefit/reason for using With on z=m instead of just m?

Comment: No, just one way of getting the job done - depending on what is going on in the table generation, things may not be evaluated in the way you think. Unfortunately, the non-working example really is non-working: it does not generate a proper graphics object when run...

Comment: It seems that the problem arises with the Dynamic[] wrap.

Comment: There was also an error in one of the Tables, it's fixed now.

Comment: Bottom line you need to use MM evaluation control/constructs to be sure the index is evaluated (which it isn't when you see the recursion related errors). I chopped the relevant parts to the code, added the `With` (again, just a primitive way for testing) and it works fine - clicking on ring segments makes inner curves appear/disappear which is I presume the intent.

Comment: It is hard to know where to start to comment on this but this is conceptually wrong -- for want of a better expression. The continued use of `Dynamic` followed by `;` indicates a failure to understand what `Dynamic` does. Before proceeding any further on this please read all the relevant docs and tutorials on `Dynamic`. `Dynamic` only updates pixels on the screen. If you suppress output (i.e. no pixels) `Dynamic` is completely redundant.  
The same section of docs also address the use of e.g. `Table[With {i=i},...],...]` and when and why it is necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to rewrite your minimal example. The main thing I have changed (apart from removing surplus `Dynamic`s) is to use downvalues of a single symbol to store the state of each sector. That is, instead of creating symbols `sector1`, `sector2` etc by string manipulation, use `sector[1]`, `sector[2]` and so on.

The definitions of `ring`, `cir`, `points1` and `points2` are fine, so I've just copied them straight from the question:

```
ring[o_, i_, s_, p_] := Module[{q, oP, iP},
   q = (s)/(2 Pi);
   oP = Table[{o Cos[k q 2 Pi/p], o Sin[k q 2 Pi/p]}, {k, 1, p}]; 
   iP = Table[{i Cos[k q 2 Pi/p], i Sin[k q 2 Pi/p]}, {k, 1, p}];
   Polygon[Flatten[{oP, Reverse@iP}, 1]]];
cir[x_, r_] := {r*Cos[x], r*Sin[x]};
points1 = Table[{
    RandomReal[{0 + m*(Pi/4), Pi/4 + m*(Pi/4) - Pi/64}],
    RandomReal[{0 + (m + 2)*(Pi/4), Pi/4 + (m + 2)*(Pi/4)}]},
   {4}, {m, 0, 7}];
points2 = Table[{points1[[n, o, 1]],
    If[Abs[points1[[n, o, 2]] - points1[[n, o, 1]]] > Pi,
     (points1[[n, o, 1]] + points1[[n, o, 2]])/2 + Pi,
     (points1[[n, o, 1]] + points1[[n, o, 2]])/2], points1[[n, o, 2]]},
   {n, 1, 4}, {o, 1, 8}];
```

I calculate all the graphics primitives (curves and ring sectors) in advance:

```
curves = Table[BezierCurve[
    {cir[points2[[o, n, 1]], 1], cir[points2[[o, n, 2]], 0.3], cir[points2[[o, n, 3]], 1]}],
   {n, 8}, {o, 1, 4}];

rings = Table[Rotate[ring[1.1, 1.05, Pi/4 - Pi/64, 1000], Pi/4*(n - 1), {0, 0}], {n, 8}];
```

For the dynamic toggling of each sector, I use downvalues of the symbol `sector` to store the states. The buttons are defined so that the n'th button toggles `sector[n]` between `True` and `False`. `Pick` is used to select the elements of `curves` for which the corresponding `sector[n]` is `True`:

```
sector[_] = True;

outRing = Table[With[{n = n}, Button[rings[[n]], sector[n] = ! sector[n]]], {n, 8}];

Graphics[{outRing, Dynamic @ Pick[curves, Array[sector, 8]]}]
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely a much better approach than my... brutish forcing of symbol names.  Thanks for the solution!